# Problem with wine 4 on Ubuntu 18.04 ( libc6 and dxvk, cannot install, broken packages)

Tags: ubuntu, wine, vulkan

Wine 4 requires `libc6` and `dxvk`, but I can't install them.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-staging-i386:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libvkd3d1:i386 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
```

When I try to install an older version from `.deb` file I can't execute wine.

How can I get `libc6 2.29` and `libvkd3d1` for 18.04?